# How to check MongoDB connection status in D?

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, d, vibed

As far as I understand from docs vibed have 2 was API for MongoDB
1. Low level
2. Hight level

Low level API have connection property, so I can connect to DB and check if connection is success with next code:

```
        auto db = new MongoConnection("localhost", 27017);
        db.connect;
        if (db.connected == true)
            writeln("Connected");
        else
            writeln("Can't connect to DB");
```

But all examples show that I need to use connect with Mongo with `connectMongoDB` class:
    `auto db = connectMongoDB("localhost").getDatabase("test");`
but this class do not have connection status method.

1. Can I return from MongoConnection `MongoClient` type and use it's in my code. If I right understand all other methods need MongoClient to get basic operation.
2. Can I check connection status with `connectMongoDB` class?
3. Why `try-catch` block, do not avail? Even if I make an incorrect connectionString, I still can not get any error message.

Comment: `connectMongoDB` is a function that returns `MongoClient`.